# Remove column break before bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, two-column

I am writing a document using the [ACM SIG Procedings template](http://www.sheridanprinting.com/typedept/sig-alternate-2013.cls) whose summarized structure is as follows (it uses 2 columns). I am using PDFLatex and Bibtex.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-2013}
\usepackage{hyperref}
....
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\input{intro}

\section{Related work}
\input{relatedwork}
....

\section{Conclusion}
\input{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

The conclusion section starts at the penultimate page. Then comes the bibliography which for some reason inserts a column break making the references section start in the right column and require an extra page. How can remove this column break? I have googled intensively searching for a solution but I have not found anything related. Is it "thebibliography" command that by default inserts this column break?

Your help will be kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your attention and time!

Comment: This does not happend by default.  What is in the `conclusion` file?

Comment: Only two plain paragraphs.

Comment: There's nothing in the definition of `thebibliography` that suggests a column break; a space is missing after a constant `0`, but it doesn't really make any harm. There *is* a bad error in the definition, but it may cause the exact contrary of your situation, namely that the title is at the bottom of a column and the references follow on the next one.

Comment: Such a plain file produces no page/column break for me.  What else do you have in your preamble?  It would be best if you posted a complete compilable document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This so embarrasing. It seems there was a hidden \pagebreak in the conclusion. Removing it worked. Shouldn't \pagebreak send the bibliography to the next page and not to the next column? My apologies for this apparent false alarm.

Comment: Within columns, `\pagebreak` opens up to the next column, not necessarily the next page.  To get to the next page, regardless of what column you're in, you need to use something like `\clearpage`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Probably that is as good an answer as any other: please convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using columns, `\pagebreak` opens up to the next column, which is not necessarily the next page.  To get to the next page, regardless of what column you're currently in, you need to use something like `\clearpage`.

Comment: That explains what was happening then. Thanks to all for your help.